# How can i access json array in php and save it in .json file

Tags: php, arrays, json

**Current PHP Code is working but I need to save JSON as I mentioned in the example** 
I need to access all data of array and save it inside the **.JSON** File

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    $fh = fopen('local.json','w');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://jsonstorage.net/api/items/46b5a62d-9a39-41ab-89f4-e75f458c9189");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $contents = curl_exec($curl);
    fwrite($fh, $contents);
    curl_close($curl);
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

**My JSON data is in this form but I need to access all data of [data]**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "adapterid": 44835,
      "rowid": 1573784208932,
      "battery": 3610,
      "createddate": "15-11-2019",
      "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
      "id": 2277491836402479600,
      "projectid": 32107,
      "rssi": -90,
      "temp": 25.75
    },
    {
      "adapterid": 44835,
      "rowid": 1573784212032,
      "battery": 3660,
      "createddate": "15-11-2019",
      "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
      "id": 2277491836402479600,
      "projectid": 32107,
      "rssi": -89,
      "temp": 25.75
    },
    {
      "adapterid": 44835,
      "rowid": 1573784215034,
      "battery": 3610,
      "createddate": "15-11-2019",
      "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
      "id": 2277491836402479600,
      "projectid": 32107,
      "rssi": -96,
      "temp": 25.75
    }
]
}
```

**the response I want is:**

```
{
  "data": [
              **I want this data** 
          ]
}
```

here is the example sample of my requirement:

```
[
    {
      "adapterid": 44835,
      "rowid": 1573784208932,
      "battery": 3610,
      "createddate": "15-11-2019",
      "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
      "id": 2277491836402479600,
      "projectid": 32107,
      "rssi": -90,
      "temp": 25.75
    },
    {
      "adapterid": 44835,
      "rowid": 1573784212032,
      "battery": 3660,
      "createddate": "15-11-2019",
      "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
      "id": 2277491836402479600,
      "projectid": 32107,
      "rssi": -89,
      "temp": 25.75
    },
    {
      "adapterid": 44835,
      "rowid": 1573784215034,
      "battery": 3610,
      "createddate": "15-11-2019",
      "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
      "id": 2277491836402479600,
      "projectid": 32107,
      "rssi": -96,
      "temp": 25.75
    }
]
```

How can I access this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the json into an associative array using `json_decode($contents, true);`

This allows you to retrieve the `data` array inside the json, then turn it back into json using `json_encode($contents['data']);` to write the data to file:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$fh = fopen('local.json', 'w');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://jsonstorage.net/api/items/46b5a62d-9a39-41ab-89f4-e75f458c9189");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$contents = curl_exec($curl);
$contents = json_decode($contents, true); // to associative array
$contents = json_encode($contents['data']); // to json, only the 'data' array
fwrite($fh, $contents); // write json 'data' array to file
curl_close($curl);
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$contents = json_decode($contents,1);
print_r($contents['data']);
```